# Grabbing the 'side' direction of the curve

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves

Is there a way of picking the 90º direction of the curve tangent? I need to drag the generated curve points in this direction, the direction perpendicular to the curve tangent and also perpendicular to the global Z axis. I can't use the normal because it changes a lot, aways trying to point away from the object's origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just finished writing the question and I realized I can cross-product the tangent with the $(0,0,1)$ vector...

Comment: +1 This would be an even better answer if you showed a screenshot of the node setup for future users to whom it might not be so obvious.